# How to copy data from table to another

Tags: sql-server, database

How to copy data from table to another

1. Insert all the instructors (except have the same ID with a student) into student table with tot_creds = 0, in the same department
2. Now delete all the newly added "students" above (note: already existing students who have tot_creds = 0 should not get deleted)

Instructor table:

```
 ID      Name           dept_name    salary
10101   Srinivasan     Comp. Sci.   65000.00
12121   Wu             Finance      90000.00
15151   Mozart         Music        40000.00
22222   Einstein       Physics      95000.00
32343   El Said        History      60000.00
33456   Gold           Physics      87000.00
45565   Katz           Comp. Sci.   75000.00
58583   Califieri      History      62000.00
76543   Singh          Finance      80000.00
```

Student:

```
ID      Name      dept_name    tot_cred
00128   Zhang     Comp. Sci.    102
12345   Shankar   Comp. Sci.    32
19991   Brandt    History       80 
23121   Chavez    Finance       110
44553   Peltier   Physics       56
45678   Levy      Physics       46
70557   Snow      Physics       0
```

i have tried this for inserting but nothing happens 0 rows affected kindly guide me

```
insert into student select ID, name, dept_name, 0 
 from instructor 
  where ID != instructor.ID
```

Comment: There will never be any rows from this query. It is not possible there can be a value for ID that is not equal to ID. You need to use a left join for this type of thing.

Comment: Is this with MySQL or Microsoft SQL Server?

Comment: i want in both mysql and sql

Comment: I don't know that you are going to find the same code that will work for both. mysql and sql server are very different. In sql server I would use the OUTPUT statement to capture the IDs of the newly inserted rows. Then you can easily join that to delete them. Or just wrap the insert a transaction with a rollback. :)

Comment: and what is for mysql

Answer (score 1):

I would use a `not exists` clause to filter out existing records.

```
insert into Student (ID, name, dept_name, tot_cred)
select ID, name, dept_name, 0
from Instructor
where not exists (
select 1
from Student
where ID = Instructor.ID
)
```

Then remove them from the Instructors table (if I understand part 2 correctly).

```
delete
from Instructor
where exists (
select 1
from Student
where ID = Instructor.ID
)
```

This assumes, though, that ID is globally unique between both Student and Instructor tables.

Comment: this code works but i want want to delete the data from student table which we insert recently.

Comment: Then why bother inserting them if you're just going to delete them immediately? If so, though, you may want to look into the [`output` clause](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx).

Comment: actually i am doing this for my database practice that's y.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this:

```
INSERT INTO student (id, name, dept_name, tot_cred)
   SELECT instructor.ID, instructor.name, instructor.dept_name, 0 
   FROM instructor LEFT JOIN student on instructor.ID = student.ID
   WHERE student.ID IS NULL
     AND instructor.tot_cred <> 0
```

this will insert instructors with non-zero total credits that don't match existing students.  Your #2 is a little cryptic so I am guessing on what you intend with that part.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO Students
    (ID, Name, dept_name, salary)
SELECT 
    I.ID, I.Name, I.dept_name, I.salary 
FROM 
    Instructors I
LEFT JOIN  
    Students S ON S.ID = I.ID 
WHERE 
    S.ID IS NULL
    AND S.tot_cred <> 0


DELETE FROM  Instructors WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID FROM STUDENT)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following approach in order to copy data from one table to another table:

```
--Insert data from one table to another table (same or different dBs)
INSERT INTO DestinationDB.dbo.DestinationTable(ColumnX, ColumnY, ColumnZ, ColumnW, ColumnT)
--If the ID column of the DestinationTable is automatically created (isIdentity) do not insert value to the ID column.
SELECT ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnC, 'Test', 1 
FROM SourceDB.dbo.SourceTable
WHERE < Search Conditions >
```